# Htaccess redirects only with www?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect my domains in the following way:

for `example1.com` to redirect to `example2.com/example1`

and for `example1.com/anything` to redirect to `example2.com/anything`

I now have one htacess file in the root directory of the `example1.com` domain with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example2.com/example1 [R=301]
```

which works, and that's great.

then, I created multiple directories with the `/anything` folders I needed to be redirected and I put htaccess file in each with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example2.com/anything [R=301]
```

which also works, but only if I put `www.example1.com/anything`. `example1.com/anything` redirects me to `example2.com/example1`

How to fix `this/possibly` more streamlined way to achieve it?

Comment: Your rule is fine and should work.Try clearing your browser cache or try a different browser to test the url.